# I'm struggling with Javascript Object manipulation to output the desired result

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have an array of objects that I'd like to group into particular keys and format.

Here is the Object I have:

```
      {
         "id": "98765",
         "things": [{
                 "clientId": "123456",
                 "val": "file1",
                 "cmpId": "54353"
             },
             {
                 "clientId": "1234",
                 "val": "file2",
                 "cmpId": "3453"
             },
             {
                 "clientId": "1234",
                 "val": "file3",
                 "cmpId": "5433"
             }
         ]
     };
```

My aim is to try and get the Object into the following format

```
{  
"id":"98765",
"things":{  
   "123456":{  
      "54353":{  
         "val":"file1"
      }
   },
   "1234":{  
      "3453":{  
         "val":"file2"
      },
      "5433":{  
         "val":"file3"
      }
   }
}
}
```

I have managed to achieve getting the 'clientId' to be a key of the Objects, but am struggling to get the campaign IDs to be nested within that Object.
This is the code I've tried

```
     const a = obj.things.reduce((ac, {clientId, ...rest})=> (ac[clientId] = rest, ac), {})
     console.log(a);
```

This gives a format of the following which obviously doesn't achieve the cmpId nesting, but also gets rid of one of my Objects as the clientId is a duplicate. I'm a bit lost about how I achieve something quite neat without horrible reams of code to achieve it.

```
{
'1234': { val: 'file3', cmpId: '5433' },
'123456': { val: 'file1', cmpId: '54353' }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the right approach. You just need to change `ac[clientId] = rest` to the structure you want:

```js
const obj = {
         "id": "98765",
         "things": [{
                 "clientId": "123456",
                 "val": "file1",
                 "cmpId": "54353"
             },
             {
                 "clientId": "1234",
                 "val": "file2",
                 "cmpId": "3453"
             },
             {
                 "clientId": "1234",
                 "val": "file3",
                 "cmpId": "5433"
             }
         ]
     };
     
obj.things = obj.things.reduce( ( res, { clientId, cmpId, ...rest } ) => {
  res[clientId] = { ...res[clientId], [cmpId]: rest };
  return res;
}, { } );

console.log( obj );
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, you also need to get the `cmpId` and then check if there is already an object for `clientId`, here is an example:

```js
const input = {
  "id": "98765",
  "things": [{
      "clientId": "123456",
      "val": "file1",
      "cmpId": "54353"
    },
    {
      "clientId": "1234",
      "val": "file2",
      "cmpId": "3453"
    },
    {
      "clientId": "1234",
      "val": "file3",
      "cmpId": "5433"
    }
  ]
};

input.things = input.things.reduce((a, {
  clientId,
  cmpId,
  ...rest
}) => {
  if (a[clientId]) {
    a[clientId][cmpId] = rest;
  } else {
    a[clientId] = {
      [cmpId]: rest
    };
  }
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.reduce()` to map/combine the `things` property, like so:

```js
const data = { "id": "98765", "things": [{ "clientId": "123456", "val": "file1", "cmpId": "54353" }, { "clientId": "1234", "val": "file2", "cmpId": "3453" }, { "clientId": "1234", "val": "file3", "cmpId": "5433" } ] };

const newData = { id: data.id,
  things: data.things.reduce((out, {clientId, cmpId, ...rest}) => //for each "thing"
    ({...out, [clientId]: {...out[clientId], [cmpId]: rest}})     //Create/merge with existing clientId
  , {})
};
    
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

This version is similar to several others here.  It's designed to avoid mutating your original structure and the allow additional properties at both levels to be passed through to the output, caring only about `things`, `clientId`, and `cmpId`.

```js
const transform = ({things, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  things: things.reduce(
    (a, {clientId, cmpId, ...rest}) => ({...a, [clientId]: {...a[clientId], [cmpId]: rest}}), 
    {}
  )
})

const data = {id: "98765", things: [{clientId: "123456", val: "file1", cmpId: "54353"}, {clientId: "1234", val: "file2", cmpId: "3453"}, {clientId: "1234", val: "file3", cmpId: "5433"}]}

console .log (
  transform (data)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

try using [JSONPath](https://jsonpath.com) incase you are aimimg to get your desired result by iterating over the the object.It is an excellent tool which basically coverts the whole json into XML